# Configure Nginx Sub Domain

Tags: nginx, matomo

I am trying to add a subdomain along side my existing website setup.

I have added the following server block to my nginx configuration located at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name stats.website.org;

   root /var/www/piwik;
   index index.php index.html;

   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/existing_website/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name website.org;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

I am getting a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error when I try stats.website.org.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a DNS resolution problem and nothing to do with your `nginx` server configuration.